# Why Angular resets selected value?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I use select list in HTML:

```
<select name="mouth" ng-model="formData.mouth" ng-required="true" class="ng-pristine ng-valid ng-valid-required" required="required">
<option value="0">A</option>
<option value="3" selected="selected">Mart</option>
</select>
```

Angular resets selected value to firts option, when I added:
`ng-model="formData.day" ng-required="true"`

What is a reason?

Comment: What does your controller look like?

Answer (score 0):

You should try using [ngSelected](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSelected). Make sure you are not setting the model value to '0' in the controller.